# How to get path of all uploaded files in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am making a rest API for multipart request API code is working fine but I am unable to get URL of multiple files any body know how to get this done code I done so far:

```
@app.route('/multiple-files-upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    randNum = random.randint(10, 900)
    appendRand = "SWM-"+str(randNum)
    date = str(datetime.date(datetime.now()))
    
    # subject = request.form['subject']
    # details = request.form['details']
    # province = request.form['province']
    # district = request.form['district']
    # tehsil = request.form['tehsil']
    # lat = request.form['lat']
    # lon = request.form['lon']
    # username = request.form['username']
    # status = request.form['status']
    files = request.files.getlist('files')
    
    errors = {}
    data = {}
    success = False

    for file in files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            appendDate = str(appendRand)+"-"+date+"-"+filename
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],appendDate))
            success = True
        else:
            errors[file.filename] = 'File type is not allowed'

    # if success and errors:
    #     errors['message'] = 'File(s) successfully uploaded'
    #     resp = jsonify(errors)
    #     resp.status_code = 500
    #     return resp

    if success:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        url = appendPath +'/'+appendDate
        data = {"URL":url}
        resp = jsonify({"Error":"flase","Code":"00",'Message': 'Files successfully uploaded',"Data":data})
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp
    else:
        resp = jsonify(errors)
        resp.status_code = 500
        return resp
```

Response I get:

```
{
    "Error": "flase",
    "Code": "00",
    "Message": "Files successfully uploaded",
    "Data": {
        "URL": "/uploads/SWM-882-2022-02-17-API.PNG"
    }
}
```

Desired response:

```
{
    "Error": "flase",
    "Code": "00",
    "Message": "Files successfully uploaded",
    "Data": {
        "URL": "/uploads/SWM-882-2022-02-17-API.PNG"
         "URL": "/uploads/SWM-882-2022-02-17-API.PNG"
          "URL": "/uploads/SWM-882-2022-02-17-API.PNG"
           "URL": "/uploads/SWM-882-2022-02-17-API.PNG"
    }
}
```

E.g. when I upload multiple files I get multiple URLs now only get 1 URL

Comment: Watch your indentation. You leave the loop and so only the object that was last processed in the iteration is processed after the loop. In addition, your JSON code contains an object with the expected URLs. However, it should be noted that the name of a property can only occur once per object. As a result, your expected response cannot be achieved.

Comment: @Detlef any alternative way to achieve this kind of response

Answer (score 3):

The example below follows your code and shows how to upload multiple files to the server using AJAX. As I am assuming you are trying.
Depending on whether an error occurs or not, a different response from the server is returned.
This contains a message and possible error messages, each of which is assigned to a file name. Furthermore, the resulting urls of the successfully uploaded files are listed.

###### Flask (app.py)

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import (
    jsonify,
    render_template,
    request,
    url_for
)
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = app.static_folder

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def allowed_file(filename):
    # Your validation code here!
    return True

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    errors = {}
    data = []
    prefix = f'SWM-{randint(10,900)}-{date.today()}'
    files = request.files.getlist('files')
    for file in files:
        if file.filename != '' and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            filename = f'{prefix}-{filename}'
            file.save(os.path.join(
                app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                filename
            ))
            data.append({ 'url': filename })
        else:
            errors[file.filename] = 'File type is not allowed'

    return jsonify({
        'message': 'An error has occurred.' if errors else 'Files successfully uploaded',
        'errors': errors,
        'data': data
    }), 400 if errors else 200
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="my-form" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      ((uri) => {
        const formElem = document.querySelector('form[name="my-form"]');
        formElem.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
          evt.preventDefault();
          fetch(uri, {
            method: 'post',
            body: new FormData(evt.target)
          }).then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => {
              console.log(data);
            });
          evt.target.reset(),
        });
      })({{ url_for('upload') | tojson }});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```